# Django Import User Profile from linkedin

Tags: python, django, api, oauth, linkedin-api

I have `django` web app, where i have some registered user, now i want to give them option to connect to `linkedin` and import their profile from `linkedin` instead of creating manually on my app. 
I have seen some libraries on `github`, but they only import when we have both `consuemer` and `secret key` of user, but in my case i don't have these, i just want my users to give option to import their profile data from `linkedin` in one click.

Answer (score 2):

[django-allauth](http://django-allauth.readthedocs.org/en/latest/providers.html#linkedin) provides what you need for getting user information from linkedin. They also connect to many other libraries if you want to give other options to connect social accounts.

Comment: Is this will be enough, i have search a lot but found only login and registration with `fb`, `twitter`, `g+` etc. need some examples or tuts for importing profiles

Comment: incomplete answer

Comment: thanks @jencko for the useful comment 2 years+ later

Comment: I am sorry but you should give some details as well. Your answer didn't solve the problem. BTW how does time matter to your incomplete answer ? @awwester